# Error with plugin in cfg file using nosetest

Tags: python, python-2.7, nose, nosetests

I have a file with the following lines:

```
suite = LazySuite(all_tests)
run(suite=suite, argv=['','-c', 'nose.cfg'] )
```

And I have this nose config file:

```
[nosetests]
stop=1
with-xunit=1
xunit-file=test.xml
```

And when I run the testsuite, the following message is showed:

```
Usage: TestSuite1.py [options]

TestSuite1.py: error: Error reading config file 'nose.cfg': no such option 'with-xunit'

Process finished with exit code 2
```

I don't know what is happening, because if I execute the xunit plugin in the cmd directly as argument, the script is executed without problems.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem.

I was defining the configure in the following lines:

```
c = Config()
cf = c.configure(argv=['','-c', 'nose.cfg'])
```

:)